# How to get last children records with parent record with EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I asked similar question but this time I want to use Entity Framework.

I have database with two tables: Customers (Id PK, LastName, State, etc) and Orders (Id PK, CustomerId FK, ProductName, Price, etc.)

I want to retrieve only customer' last order's details together with customer name.
I started with:

```
var orders = from o in db.Orders
where o.Customer.State == "NY"
select o;
var lastOrders = orders.
Where(x => x.Customer.Orders.Where(y=>!y.IsCancelled).
OrderByDescending(z => z.Id).First().Id == x.Id);
```

But I have feeling that this may not be efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
var query = from c in db.Customers
            where c.State == "NY"
               && c.Orders.Any(o => !o.IsCancelled)
            select new { 
                Name = c.Name,
                Order = c.Orders.Where(o => !o.IsCancelled)
                                .OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).FirstOrDefault()
            };

var customersWithLastOrder = query.ToList();
```

It gives you a collection of an anonymous type which contains the name and the last order of the customer.

**Edit**

(`Where(...).Count() > 0` replaced by `Any(...)`, thanks to BritishDeveloper!)

Comment: +1 That's the best way. A few niggles though: 1) line 3 - `c.Orders.Any(o=>!o.IsCancelled)` and 2) line 7 - `.OrderBy(o=>i.Id).LastOrDefault()`

Comment: @BritishDeveloper: Thanks! The `Any` method is indeed nicer, I will edit my code. But unfortunately `LastOrDefault()` isn't supported in LINQ to Entities, so we can't use it here.